# Why is my fill for my center node not where it should be?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found some code to make a wheel graph online and I understand all of it except this part : node at ($(A 1)!.5!(A 6)$).  I think this is the circle at the center, but I can't get the red filled circle to sit there.  What does this part mean and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz, graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
\graph[nodes={draw, circle, fill=black}, radius=.5cm,
           empty nodes]        { subgraph C_n [n=9,m=3,clockwise,radius=3cm,name=A]-- mid};
        \node[shape=circle, fill=red] at  ($(A 1)!.5!(A 6)$) (){}; %WHAT IS HAPPENING
        \foreach \i [count=\xi from 2]  in {1,4,7}{
        \node[shape=circle, fill=red] at (A \i){}; }
        \foreach \i [count=\xi from 2]  in {2,3,5,6,8,9}{
        \node[fill=black] at (A \i){}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `($(A 1)!.5!(A 6)$)` means "halfway (0.5) between nodes (A 1) and (A 6)". (A 1) is the node at the top; (A 6) is the sixth node along starting with (A 1) running clockwise. Since it's not directly below (A 1) but slightly to the left, so is midway between it and (A 1). But I'm not an expert on this stuff either.

Comment: Also, could you explain what you mean by "fix it"? What is it supposed to be like? The middle is just `(0,0)` so `\node[shape=circle, fill=red] at (0,0){};` would put the red circle in the middle, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want the following result:

[image]

It is produced by:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
\graph[nodes={draw, circle, fill=black}, 
       empty nodes]        
{subgraph C_n [n=9,m=3,clockwise,radius=3cm,name=A]-- mid};
\node[shape=circle, fill=red] {};       
\foreach \i in {1,4,7}
{
\node[shape=circle, fill=red] at (A \i){}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is "fix" for your code. As you see, for centering of red dot you not need to calculate position of center since wheel is drawn around coordinate `(0,0)`. In your case nodes at this coordinate not need to explecite to define this coordinate. However, you can write it as `\node[shape=circle, fill=red] at (0,0) {};`.

Why the red dot is not centered in the wheel is explained in the very good @frabjous comment.